# Access to the data of a workbook in another repertory

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the access of the data in a workbook in another repertory but I don't know the syntax, can you help me please ?

I have tried something like that but it doesn't work

```
Workbooks("U:\a.xlsx").Sheets("a").Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a value you need to open that file first.

```
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\a.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True) 'readonly if you only need to read

'read the value
Debug.Print MyWb.Worksheets("a").Range("A2")

'close it after reading
MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

---

Or if you want to do it hidden in the background without showing the workbook:

```
'open a new hidden Excel
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Set ExApp = New Excel.Application 
ExApp.Visible = False

'open the workbook in that hidden ExApp
Dim MyWb As Workbook
Set MyWb = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\a.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

'read the value
Debug.Print MyWb.Worksheets("a").Range("A2")

'close it after reading
MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

'close hidden Excel
ExApp.Quit
```

Here a proper error handling might be useful to ensure the ExApp is closed in case of any error. Otherwise the process will stay open.

Comment: hello it shows me this error, object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @guenoon Then either your file `"U:\a.xlsx"` or the worksheet named `a` does not exist. In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Oh no my bad, I forgot to put set before mywb. Nevermind it works perfectly, but I'll try the other solution, without showing the workbook. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to open the workbook to access it.

Like:

```
Dim otherwb as Workbook
Set otherwb = Workbooks.Open("U:\a.xlsx")

Dim otherwbRange as Range
Set otherwbRange = otherwb.Sheets("a").Range("A2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Object for the workbook first.

Try something like:

```
Dim excel_wb2 As Excel.Workbook

Set excel_wb2 = Excel.Workbooks.Open("U:\a.xlsx")

x = excel_wb2.Sheets("a").Range("A2")
```